# How to skip Yahoo! news page and go directly to inbox?

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo

How do you skip the Yahoo! news page and go directly to your inbox? All  suggestions have not worked.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site as it doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. It's entirely unclear what suggestions have not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Access the URL for the subdirectory for Yahoo Mail at `mail.yahoo.com` rather than going to `yahoo.com` to access your account. This will redirect you to a cookied link to the login page if you are not already logged in, and when you enter your credentials, you will be directed by cookie to the Yahoo webmail rather than the Yahoo homepage. Also, you can use any email software that allows access to mail servers through POP3 or IMAP.